# WiFi disappears randomly 22.04

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

I've been using Ubuntu 22.04.03 for a while and once in a while WiFi will disappear from the icons above and the settings page. Most of the sites I've checked regarding this issue resolve the problem of no WiFi upon installation, but this randomly happens during use.

Once this happens, restarting the network from the terminal does not seem to make a difference (`sudo service NetworkManager restart`)

Rebooting usually helps but the problem persists.

sudo lshw -C network recognizes it.

```
>  *-network                 
>        description: Wireless interface
>        product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
>        vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
>        physical id: 0
>        bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
>        logical name: wlp1s0
>        version: 32
>        serial: e4:aa:ea:60:f1:a9
>        width: 64 bits
>        clock: 33MHz
>        capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
>        configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=6.2.0-35-generic
> firmware=WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00157-QCARMSWPZ-1 ip=192.168.213.114 latency=0
> link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
>        resources: irq:71 memory:c0200000-c03fffff

rfkill list
    0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
    1: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
    2: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

Is this a common bug? Is there a safe workaround?
It's a laptop so I also don't have an ethernet adapter.

**EDIT #1:**

```
 iwconfig; cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp1s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Gaj's Xiaomi 11T"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 12:17:8E:37:28:BB   
          Bit Rate=130 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=66/70  Signal level=-44 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:63   Missed beacon:0

[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `iwconfig; cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager service`. Also do: `service NetworkManager status` and `service --status-all`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terminal

```
sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
sudo iwconfig wlp1s0 power off
```

Reboot
That wifi should do better with power management off